# Save image as png and allow user to share image to social media

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I want same the image once it is converted. I tried canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); but that did not work for me. I tried the code below and while it created an img, it didn't display the screenshot. I am a newbie using javascript. Can you help please.

```
function showImage() 
{
html2canvas($('#hpImplement'), 
{
    onrendered: function(canvas) 
   {
       var elem = document.createElement("img");
       elem.setAttribute("src", canvas);
       elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
       document.getElementById("hpShare").appendChild(elem);

   },
});
```

}

I even tried:

```
function showImage() 
{
    html2canvas($('#hpImplement'), 
   {
        onrendered: function(canvas) 
       {
           var theCanvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
           var elem = document.createElement("img");
           elem.setAttribute("src", theCanvas);
           elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
           document.getElementById("hpShare").appendChild(elem);

       },
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4ekotrph/  
However to share an image in social media without requiring the user to download it to disk then upload to another website, the social website needs a way to access the image on its own, so it has to be saved on a public web server somewhere.

Comment: This is so odd. Its working on JSFiddle but when i try and run the code on google chrome via the code editor, it doesn't run!

Comment: @pawel Am I missing a particular plugin? I have the html2canvas plugin, I have the JQuery 1.8.2 plugin.

Comment: @pawel It does not seem to read var theCanvas = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); when I add this statement, it does nothing but when i code elem.setAttribute("src", canvas); it creates an img tag but does not display the image

Comment: Maybe you try to render the screenshot before it's been drawn on the screen, i.e. the scripts are executed before the page has been loaded. Common problem: script in <head> tries to do something with elements in <body> which do not yet exist at the moment of execution. Try `window.onload = showImage;` to execute the script after everything has loaded.